# RxJs: Wait on value from Observable, if it doesn't come after a specified time period do some stuff and wait again, after n tries throwError

Tags: rxjs, observable, wait, repeat

So what's my case:
I'm sending signaling message to network and want to wait for response, if that doesn't come within 2 seconds, I want to send the signaling message again. After 3 retries, I want to raise an error and log in somewhere.
I'm subscribing to observable simplified below:

```
from(messages).pipe(filter(value => condition(value)))
```

and I need to wait, till it emits the expected value and simultaneously do the process described above. I'd appreciate every help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [`timeout(2000)`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/timeout) will help you with limiting time to 2sec
- [`retry(3)`](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/retry/) will give you maximum 3 retries
- and [`catchError`](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/catch/) or `subscribe` will let you handle failed final attempt

e.g.:

```js
signal().pipe(
  timeout(2000),
  retry(3)
)
.subscribe({
  next: () => {},
  error: () => {}
})
```

Heres an [interactive example](https://observable-playground.github.io/gist/c526cd7d75713adbf86b60db5860e333) (*try playing with timings in the `switchMap` callback*)

NOTE: if you want to do other operations with the source stream -- you might [`share()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/share) it